# Where to declare lots of constant objects?

Tags: android

This might look like a stupid question but I actually have objects - let's call the object "Cocktail" - that contains a certain amount of fields such as cocktail name, list of ingredients, recipe, etc... 
So basically what I would like to do is have my cocktails list available when my application needs it, but I do not really know how to store them. I thought of declaring all cocktails in Android string arrays such as following :
<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="first_cocktail_name">
        <item>ingredient1</item>
        <item>ingredient2</item>
        <item>ingredient3</item>
        <item>recipe</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array
        name="second_cocktail_name">
        <item>ingredient1</item>
        <item>ingredient2</item>
        <item>ingredient3</item>
        <item>recipe</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And so on, but problem is I don't have the possibility of declaring item key so retrieve all the info will be a bit tedious, for example if the number of ingredients vary between different cocktails index retrieving will not work... 
I'm not a big fan of hard-coding all my cocktail objects directly in code when app starts either so I don't really know what to do with that... 
Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: I do have my own recipe app and I prefer to store all my constant data like ingredients, method steps etc. in database. I do have local and remote database.

Comment: I'd use SQLite if I were you. I'd just retreive the information during the start of the app and i'd have access to it whenever i need it

Comment: Yeah I also thought about this solution but wanted a confirmation before starting implementing a database... then I think I'll use that !